# How to remove button borders inside Nativescript CardView on Android?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm having some difficulty removing the border on a button that is inside the Nativescript-CardView plugin.

[image]

html

```
<CardView #item elevation="50" margin="10">
    <GridLayout rows="auto, auto, auto" columns="*, *, *">
        <Image src="~/images/shop.jpg" stretch="aspectFit" colSpan="3" row="0" ></Image>
        <Button text="&#xE88E;" class="Material btn" row="1" col="0" ></Button>
        <Button text="&#xE8CC;" class="Material btn" row="1" col="1" ></Button>
        <Button text="&#xE530;" class="Material btn" row="1" col="2" ></Button>
     </GridLayout>
</CardView>
```

css

```
.btn {
  font-size: 20;
  margin:4;
  border-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  border-width: 0;
  border-style: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright so it's nothing related to the CardView. Just buttons on Android 5.1 (Lollipop)+ 
Try these two rules with your class and it will work. You won't need `border-color: transparent` with this either.

`border-width: 0.1;
background-color: transparent;`

Answer (score 0):

With the current versions of NativeScript, the 0.1-hack doesn't work anymore. Instead, set the border to 1 and make it transparent or match the background-color:

```css
border-width: 1;
border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
```

See here for more information: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2626#issuecomment-261493611